# Trouble deleting a specific row in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, row

I have been trying to delete a specific row from a table using php. I followed a guide online that made a table with the data in it with a delete button next to each row.

When the delete button is clicked it should delete the row using the primary key "id". Instead it goes through the 'if' statement and echoes 'Error'.

Using echo var_dump($_GET) I believe it is passing the id through but the WHERE clause is somehow not receiving the id.

If i remove the WHERE clause, it will work but will of course delete all the data inside the table

PHPDelete

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // host name 
$username="root"; // database username 
$password="root"; // database password 
$db_name="school"; // database name 
$tbl_name="Student"; // table name 



mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");


$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>
<!--creating the table -->
<table width="400" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"> 
<tr>
<td colspan="5" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Delete data</strong> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>id</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Name</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Age</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Username</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<tr>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['Name']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['Age']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['Username']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><a href='phpDelete2.php?id=$id'>delete</a></td>


</tr>

<?php




// close while loop 
}

?>

</table>

<?php
// close connection; 
mysql_close();
?>
```

and phpDelete2

```
<?php


$host="localhost"; // host name 
$username="root"; // database username 
$password="root"; // database password 
$db_name="school"; // database name 
$tbl_name="Student"; // table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select database");

// get value of id that sent from address bar 


$id = $_GET['id'];

// Delete data in mysql from row that has this id



$sql="DELETE FROM $tbl_name";

$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully deleted
if($result){
echo "Deleted Successfully";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='index.php'>Back to main page</a>";
}

else {
echo "error";
}
?> 

<?php
// close connection 
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Narrow down your troublesome lines and update with a post. At the moment, there is alot of unnecessary information within this question

Comment: FYI, mysql_functions are deprecated as of php 5.5.x! You should switch to mysqli instead. http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never bothered actually echoing your ID value:

```
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><a href='phpDelete2.php?id=$id'>delete</a></td>
```

should be

```
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><a href='phpDelete2.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>'>delete</a></td>
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

As well, **NEVER** put something as dangerous as a delete operation into a simple link. Consider what happens if your browser decides to "preload" all linked pages? Suddenly you're deleting EVERYTHING you've listed on the page.

Your DELETE query also doesn't bother using the ID you tried passing in, and will simply delete EVERYTHING in your table. It should be

```
DELETE FROM yourtable WHERE id = ID_VALUE_GOES_HERE
```

Be aware of [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) as well...